# Read from custom .config file

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am building an application using MVC 4 which makes several web service calls to a third party application. The API has a couple params such as a Token which must always be passed. I want to store these variables in a configuration file so I created a file called API.config in the root directory of the project. However I'm not really sure how I can read from this configuration file in my classes that make the web service calls.

I tried this but it would not compile:

```
Configuration conf = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~/API.config");
private string apiToken = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["APIToken"];
```

Error:

> Error 1 A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field,
>   method, or property

I'm new to ASP.NET so I'm not even sure if this is the best approach to storing globals in ASP.NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical way to store strong globals like this in an ASP.NET application is to put them in the AppSettings section of your web.config file.

Then you can get them out with ConfiguraitonManager.AppSettings as in your question.

Comment: This worked great, but just out of curiosity is there a way to read from a custom .config file? Lets say you have tons of global settings and you don't want to clutter Web.config, is it best to create a seperate config or use Properties -> Settings suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Properties->Settings.  I haven't used it in MVC but it should work the same as winforms as long as you are using the values server-side in the controller